# Pandas Dataframe - Como fazer para usar um valor anterior que não seja NA para calculo

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tendo um dataframe como o que segue de exemplo:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,100],['B',2,None],['C',3,None],['D',4,182],['E',5,None]], columns=['A','B','C'])
   A  B      C
0  A  1  100.0
1  B  2    NaN
2  C  3    NaN
3  D  4  182.0
4  E  5    NaN
```

Eu gostaria de calcular, sem usar o apply, a diferença da coluna 'C', da linha 3 para a linha 0.

Detalhe é que não é fixo esse espaço entre linhas com NaN, então não consigo utilizar o `df.C.shift(2)` por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função `diff()` para calcular a diferença entre linhas. Como os `NaN` devem ser ignorados, basta removê-los antes com `df[~df['C'].isnull()]`:

```
>>> df[~df['C'].isnull()]['C'].diff()
0     NaN
3    82.0
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Se quiser juntar ao `df` original, basta fazer um `pd.merge` pelo `index`:

```
diff_series = df[~df['C'].isnull()]['C'].diff()
diff_series.name = 'C diff'
pd.merge(
    df,
    diff_series,
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    how='left'
)
```

E o resultado será:

```
    A   B   C      C diff
0   A   1   100.0  NaN
1   B   2   NaN    NaN
2   C   3   NaN    NaN
3   D   4   182.0  82.0
4   E   5   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Acredito que usando `df['C'].notnull()` ficaria mais intuitivo que a negação do `isnull()`. Tambem daria pra evitar o uso do `merge` atribuindo o `diff_series` diretamente a uma nova coluna ao DF, pois a intersecção entre eles é feito pelos indices (que foram preservados), algo como: `df['C diff] = diff_series`. Aliás, é uma resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Sem usar "apply" fica ineficiente - basicamente você tem que olhar o conteúdo de célula por célula da coluna, subindo desde o "3". Dá para usar `math.isnan` para testar se o valor é `nan`.

Uma função para isso usando um for e if explícitos poderia ser:

```py
def diff_first_previous_valid(series, index):
    for value in series[index - 1::-1]:
        if not math.isnan(value):
            return series[index] - value
    raise ValueError("No previous valid value")
```

E, usando isso interativamente:

```
In [241]: diff_first_previous_valid(df["C"], 3)                                                                                                                                    
Out[241]: 82.0
```

Usando apply, o jeito pode ser criar uma coluna intermediária - que duplique cada valor para baixo se o próximo valor for NaN -
no caso precisamos de uma funçãozinha também, para "esticar" os valores válidos para baixo.

Este "approach" é melhor se você vai repetir a operação várias (=algumas dezenas) de vezes na mesma coluna - senão, buscar o número em cada operação é melhor:

```py
def fill_nans(col, first=0):
    previous_val = first
    result = []
    for v in col:
        if math.isnan(v):
            result.append(previous_val)
        else:
            result.append(v)
            previous_val = v
    return result
```

```py
In [245]: x = fill_nans(df["C"])                                                                                                                                                   

In [246]: x[3] - x[2]                                                                                                                                                              
Out[246]: 82.0
```

Comment: para que criar uma função de fill_nans, se a mesma já está implementada no pandas? Veja a [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: não tinha visto que o fillna do Pandas já tem essa funcionalidade. Mas é bom as vezes pras pessoas verem que nem tudo é mágica, e que a lógica e os elementos básicos da linguagem de programação podem resolver qualquer problema, e não esperar toda vez que exista uma mágica no Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTA**: A solução apresentada abaixo **NÃO** irá atender caso os números já existentes sejam repetidos.

### Definindo dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,100],['B',2,None],['C',3,None],['D',4,182],['E',5,None]], columns=['A','B','C'])
```

### Criando uma nova coluna, cópia da coluna C e substituindo NaN pela última observação válida

```
>>> df['D'] = df['C'].fillna(method='ffill')

>>> df
   A  B      C      D
0  A  1  100.0  100.0
1  B  2    NaN  100.0
2  C  3    NaN  100.0
3  D  4  182.0  182.0
4  E  5    NaN  182.0
```

### Calculando diferenças

```
>>> df['diferenca'] = df['D'].diff()
```

### Resultado

```
>>> df

   A  B      C      D  diferenca
0  A  1  100.0  100.0        NaN
1  B  2    NaN  100.0        0.0
2  C  3    NaN  100.0        0.0
3  D  4  182.0  182.0       82.0
4  E  5    NaN  182.0        0.0
```

### Deixando apenas os resultados

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df['diferenca'].replace({0: np.nan}, inplace=True)

>>> df
   A  B      C      D  diferenca
0  A  1  100.0  100.0        NaN
1  B  2    NaN  100.0        NaN
2  C  3    NaN  100.0        NaN
3  D  4  182.0  182.0       82.0
4  E  5    NaN  182.0        NaN
```

### Voltando a **nota** inicial...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,182],['B',2,None],['C',3,None],['D',4,182],['E',5,None]], columns=['A','B','C'])

>>> df
   A  B      C
0  A  1  182.0
1  B  2    NaN
2  C  3    NaN
3  D  4  182.0
4  E  5    NaN

>>> df['D'] = df['C'].fillna(method='ffill')

>>> df
   A  B      C      D
0  A  1  182.0  182.0
1  B  2    NaN  182.0
2  C  3    NaN  182.0
3  D  4  182.0  182.0
4  E  5    NaN  182.0

>>> df['diferenca'] = df['D'].diff()

>>> df
   A  B      C      D  diferenca
0  A  1  182.0  182.0        NaN
1  B  2    NaN  182.0        0.0
2  C  3    NaN  182.0        0.0
3  D  4  182.0  182.0        0.0
4  E  5    NaN  182.0        0.0

>>> df['diferenca'].replace({0: np.nan}, inplace=True)

>>> df
   A  B      C      D  diferenca
0  A  1  182.0  182.0        NaN
1  B  2    NaN  182.0        NaN
2  C  3    NaN  182.0        NaN
3  D  4  182.0  182.0        NaN
4  E  5    NaN  182.0        NaN
>>>
```

Neste caso não haveriam resultados